# How do I detect if other apps are playing audio in background?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I want to implement an app that can detect any audio playing in the background by other apps.

ex: If there is playing music on Spotify, the Flutter app should notice that there is music playing in the background. Is it possible?

Comment: This might help: https://pub.dev/packages/nowplaying

Comment: Not working, we read the whole doc but did not find anything : (